# ResourceNotFoundException in search method

Tags: spring, spring-rest, spring-repositories

I'm trying to expose in Rest my repository written in Spring

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "product", path = "product")
interface ProductRepository : MongoRepository<ProductBean, Long> {
    @RestResource(path = "findByBizid")
    fun findByBizid(@Param("bizid") bizid : String): List<ProductBean>
}
```

Compilation is ok, no warning.
If I understood well, the following url should return my custom query method
http://127.0.0.1:8080/product/search/findByBizid?bizid=AB

But I got an empty response and a spring exception is raised and displayed in the spring console of Intellijidea:

> WARN 39290 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
>   .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused
>   by Handler execution:
>   org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException:
>   Resource not found!

I spend a full night on it, I'm completly lost

I tried to simplify my code, copy paste some tutorial examples, nothing worked.

I figured out that [127.0.0.1:8080/product/search](http://127.0.0.1:8080/product/search) method is not working either. Even if I am removing my customs methods.

Any idea how to debug this?

Anthony

Update:
 I forgot to tell that classical repository list is running well: 127.0.0.1:8080/product is retrieving all product in the db

Comment: do you have context path set in your application.properties? Can you paste your console output here.

Comment: I forgot to tell that classical repository list is running well: 127.0.0.1:8080/product. I tried to add context path it doesn't help, my console output is the warning above

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm facing the same issue and spent quite a lot of time in figuring out the issue but no luck till now.
I have the exact same issue.

Comment: Hi @RajWadhwa, sorry I wasn't. I globally switched to clojure.